# How to configure log4net with VS 2015 for an Integration Test?

Tags: c#, log4net, vstest

I am working on an Integration Test for a REST Endpoint that connects to a vendors Rest Api on a hardware device.  My software has to be tested on the physical device periodically.  I created a test project (VSTest VS 2015) and I want to add logging to my test harness.  I realize that there is a tremendous amount of documentation on log4net, but I still can't make it work.  My goal is to log to the console and also to a file.  The vendor wants a log file to validate that my tests completed.

First, I initialize log4net to read a standalone file.

```
using log4net.Config;
using log4net;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyProgram
{
    [TestClass]
    public class AssemblyInitializer
    {
        private static ILog log = null;

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void Configure(TestContext Context)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting log4net setup and configuration");

            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.properties"));
            log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AssemblyInitializer));
            log.Debug("log4net initialized for Integration Test");

            Debug.WriteLine("Completed log4net setup and configuration");

        }
    }
}
```

My log4net.properties file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionpattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %message%newline"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="IntegrationTests.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
        </level>
    </root>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

I don't think the Test Explorer reads the Assembly.Info file, but I included a reference just in case.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = false)]
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of.  I am out of ideas.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't actually said what's wrong, so I'm guessing the file is not being created in the location you expect. But a few notes: 1) a standalone log4net config file does not need to be wrapped in a  `<configuration>` section. 2) you're loading the config from a "log4net.properties" file, but does that exist in the location that you expect? 3) enable log4net internal debugging, and check the output from that.

Comment: Have you considered using using NLog instead?  I found it much easier to wrap my head around their approach to configuration.  And as far as I can tell it offers all the same features.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I am just getting back to this issue so sorry for the delay.  I removed the <configuration> tags which I was using to rid myself of the green squigglies in VS.  I verified that the log4nt.properties file is being read.  I went ahead and wrote a new function which is working -- I'll post below.

Comment: Now, I realize there isn't anything in my original code that creates or exposes a repository.  If that is important for this type of implementation, I don't see it in the documentation.
Maybe the code is working and can't find the log file and @stuartd suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works.  It is not the same implementation, but I am getting both loggers to work.  See my above comments.  I believe that the log file was either in an unknown location, or I should have accessed a repository along the way.  The following code works great and initializes before my tests are run, and logs my test results as needed.

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Layout;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MyProgram
{
    [TestClass]
    public class AssemblyInitializer
    {

        private static ILog log = null;

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void Configure(TestContext Context)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting log4net setup and configuration");

            Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
            hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();

            PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline";
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

            FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
            fileAppender.Name = "Integration Test FileAppender";
            fileAppender.File = @"Logs\IntegrationTest.log";
            fileAppender.AppendToFile = false;
            fileAppender.Layout = patternLayout;
            fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(fileAppender);

            ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
            consoleAppender.Name = "Integration Test ConsoleAppender";
            consoleAppender.Target = Console.Out.ToString();
            consoleAppender.ActivateOptions();
            consoleAppender.Layout = patternLayout;
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(consoleAppender);

            hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
            hierarchy.Configured = true;

            log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AssemblyInitializer));
            log.Debug("log4net initialized for Integration Test");

            Debug.WriteLine("Completed log4net setup and configuration");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to expand on my comment.  Because Log4Net drove me insane too.

This is all that's in my App.config in my Test project for NLog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <nlog autoReload="true"
        throwExceptions="true"
        internalLogLevel="Debug" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-test.log" >
    <targets>
      <target type="Console" name="console" error="true"/>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

You define a target which is a destination for logging and then specify which loggers write to that target.

They want you to use the LoggingManger to create a logger (a source) for every class you want to log from.  But I just wrapped a single logger in a static class and  created some pass-thru methods.  You lose some details that the logger could automatically capture for you (e.g. the exact site of the logging call), but I usually have sufficent detail in the message I'm writing to log.
~
Nlog is on Github https://github.com/NLog/NLog.   Log4Net is still svn.   That tells me something.

There also some nice Windows forms targets for Nlog available on NuGet.

Comment: `'They want you to use the LoggingManger to create a logger (a source) for every class you want to log from.`   That's what I use [this.Log()](https://github.com/ferventcoder/this.Log) for